# Ошибка: "Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in target sqlite-simple"

Tags: sql, sqlite, haskell

Пытаюсь установить SQLite в Haskell, но он выдает ошибку:

```
D:\hq>cabal install sqlite-simple
Resolving dependencies...
Up to date
Warning: You asked to install executables, but there are no executables in
target: sqlite-simple. Perhaps you want to use --lib to install libraries
instead.
```

Можете подсказать, что с этим сделать?

Comment: А как вы поняли сообщение об ошибке?

Comment: Ну он написал что я прошу установить исполняемый файл, но их он не находит

Comment: Ну он же предлагает: cabal install --lib  sqlite-simple. Почему вы не попробовали?

Comment: Блин, а я почему то вводила без -- .Спасибо Большое)))

Comment: @KseniaLyashenko, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814) ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо устанавливать так:

```
cabal install --lib sqlite-simple
```